# nlohmann json error on compile access protected member

Tags: c++, json

When I include json.hpp from the nlohmann json.hpp, I get this error all the time:
json.hpp(2544): error C2248: 'std::basic_istream>::basic_istream': cannot access protected member declared in class 'std::basic_istream>'

Does anyone have any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: You should paste the section of code as well where it is throwing the error. The latest code on github is quite different now.

Comment: Is this issue still existing?